# Can I specify field names in a compact record dtype creation?

Tags: python, numpy, types

In numpy, `dtype('i4, (5)f8')` is short for `dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8', (5,))])`, as documented at [Specifying and constructing data types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing):

> Numarray introduced a short-hand notation for specifying the format of a record as a comma-separated string of basic formats.
>
> A basic format in this context is an optional shape specifier followed by an array-protocol type string. Parenthesis are required on the shape if it has more than one dimension. NumPy allows a modification on the format in that any string that can uniquely identify the type can be used to specify the data-type in a field. The generated data-type fields are named 'f0', 'f1', ..., 'f' where N (>1) is the number of comma-separated basic formats in the string. If the optional shape specifier is provided, then the data-type for the corresponding field describes a sub-array.

My question is: Is there any shorthand notation if I want to name my fields explicitly?  For example, for `dtype([("spam", "f4", (3,)), ("eggs", "f8", (2,2))])`?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

Several examples with user defined field names:

```
Using array-protocol type strings:
>>> np.dtype([('a','f8'),('b','S10')])
```

...

```
Using tuples. int is a fixed type, 3 the field’s shape. void is a flexible type, here of size 10:
>>> np.dtype([('hello',(np.int,3)),('world',np.void,10)])
```

...

```
Using dictionaries. Two fields named ‘gender’ and ‘age’:
>>> np.dtype({'names':['gender','age'], 'formats':['S1',np.uint8]})
```

But no evidence of a syntax for adding names to 'i4, (5)f8' input.  Next step is to see if we can find the code that parses `dtype` inputs.

`numpy/core/records.py` seems to do most of the `dtype` creation.  `numpy/core/_internal.py` `_commastring` parses the 'short cut'.

It uses:

```
format_re = re.compile(asbytes(
                       r'(?P<order1>[<>|=]?)'
                       r'(?P<repeats> *[(]?[ ,0-9L]*[)]? *)'
                       r'(?P<order2>[<>|=]?)'
                       r'(?P<dtype>[A-Za-z0-9.]*(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9,.]+\])?)'))
```

to parse the string.  It doesn't look for `names`.  My guess is it was written for `numarray`, a `numpy` predecessor that did not use fieldnames.  It shouldn't be hard to write your own parser. :)